# Is it improper to define matrices as being $n \times m$ rather than $m \times n$?

Tags: notation

For whatever reason, I have always defined matrices as being $n \times m$, and that is how I have been defining matrices throughout my dissertation. Recently however, I have noticed that nearly every other source primarily defines matrices as being $m \times n$. Is the later more formal notation? Should I go through my whole dissertation to change the notation? How important is it?

Comment: The point is not whether one says "n by m" or "m by n" but whether the first number counts rows or counts columns

Comment: The convention I'm using is that $n \times m$ means $n$ rows and $m$ columns.

Comment: Then I think that would be fine, although it might cause some readers a bit of confusion when they see an unexpected expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is generally a good idea to keep things alphabetical, unless there is a good reason to do otherwise.

With matrices, it can be okay because an $n\times m$ matrix is really a linear transformation from $\mathbb{F}^m\to \mathbb{F}^n$ (where $\mathbb{F}$ is your field of definition), and so viewed this way, the $m$-dimensional space comes before the $n$-dimensional space.

So I think you are okay sticking with what you have.

Comment: Yes. But when it comes to variables for natural numbers, $n$ is the first letter of the alphabet.

Comment: **N**ah.  $i$ is a perfectly good natural number.  :-p

Comment: I also have defined vector spaces $U, V, W$ of dimensions $n,m,q$ respectively to define an $n \times m \times q$ tensor in $U \otimes V \otimes W$. Although tensors can also be interpreted as linear operators, it seems like this notation may be less acceptable. Would you agree?

Comment: @Powerspawn It can really depend on a few factors, such as what is common in your field of study, etc...  I'd recommend talking to your adviser.

Comment: As an example of a field-specific convention: in statistics the dimensions of a design matrix are traditionally referred to as $n \times p$, with $n$ the number of measurements and $p$ the number of parameters (variables): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely fine to do so.

Look at [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22matrix%20of%20order%20n%20by%20m%22&rlz=1C1CHBD_en&biw=1920&bih=937&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AOaemvJQsBxMJnFsYE4pS_TEWssolGbxqQ%3A1631812529132&ei=sXtDYa3KB_q_3LUP5ua7mAI&oq=%22matrix%20of%20order%20n%20by%20m%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2396.5609.0.5766.2.2.0.0.0.0.200.200.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0._FcmDsGvvpc). See how many authors/books have already used it.

Comment: The point is not whether one says "n by m" or "m by n" but whether the first number counts rows or counts columns.

Comment: In that case, in common parlance, it is rows first.